# Controlling the rate of messages consumption in HornetQ

Tags: hornetq, consumer

We want to control the rate at which a consumer can consume messages in HornetQ.

The problem is that when we use the ServerLocator.setConsumerMaxRate(int) method, we get always 1 message per second, regardless of the value we pass.

When we don’t call this method, the consuming rate is fast (much more than 1 per second).

Our code:

```
        TransportConfiguration connectorConfig = new TransportConfiguration(InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName());

        ServerLocator locator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(connectorConfig);

        locator.setAckBatchSize(ackBatchSize);
        locator.setConsumerWindowSize(CONSUMER_WINDOW_SIZE);
        locator.setClientFailureCheckPeriod(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        locator.setConnectionTTL(-1);
        locator.setConsumerMaxRate(10);
```

The question is - how to control the consumption rate ? and why this setting does not affect the rate ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this method from ClientSession class?:

```
ClientConsumer createConsumer(String queueName, String filter, int windowSize, int maxRate, boolean browseOnly) throws HornetQException;
```